# Social Media website refresh issue

Tags: php

Okay, so I'm in the process of making a social network website like Facebook. (not so that I can try to create the next facebook, but so I can learn how to do it) Overall its coming good, but I have a few issues. My basic layout is that I have a postFrame.php with loops through all the posts that are in the database. And on the posts.php page, I load postFrame.php dynamically with the jquery .load() function. I also refresh the table with the setTimeout function. It refreshes every five seconds. So my posts are loaded on my posts.php page dynamically and refreshed every five seconds. In my posts frame, at the bottom of each post, there is a place where you can comment on that post. (just like facebook) The only problem is when typing into the comment box, it still refreshes and after five seconds it removes everything that was in the textarea comment field.

Now, Facebook loads any new posts and comments automatically, and your comment doesn't get erased every few seconds. How are they loading new stuff and yet not refreshing the textareas in the posts? My guess is that they don't use .load(), but they use something else that I don't know about. If anyone knows this any help is greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: im create a similar social network as you one tip avoid using total content refreshes use ajax instead

Answer (score 0):

use Ajax to get content dont reload whole page. overview [HERE](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Okay, in still not sure how to load the frame and get new stuff, but don't refresh the comment boxes in the frame